# Comparing distances using longitude and latitude between two files

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, csv

I have two files that I want to join together. The two files are represented like this:

```
Hour  Longitude Latitude 
12:00 116.5      39.5
```

The other file is like this:

```
Some_datas Longitude Latitude Some_other_datas ...
x          116.529     39.521     x                ...
x          116.632     39.471     x                ...
x          116.233     39.556     x                ...
x          116.445     39.990     x                ...
etc..
```

And I want to get from the second file, all the rows and put them in another file but only if the longitude and the latitude are close together (let's say 15 kilometers).

By using a function that I found:

```
import geopy.distance

coords_1 = (116.5, 39.5)
coords_2 = (x,y)  # Where x and y are longitude and latitude from the second file

print geopy.distance.vincenty(coords_1, coords_2).km
```

How can I make it so it reads all the points of the second file, check if it's under 15 kilometers, if yes, put them in another csv file.

Comment: Why don't you load both files to the file you are working with, with the pd.read_csv method, and then create a new csv based on whether or not they pass your condition  by creating a new dataframe and using the pd.to_csv method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to `zip` both columns, get the distance and, compare creating a boolean list:

```
from geopy.distance import vincenty

#coordinates are swapped
coords_1 = (39.5, 116.4)
mask = [vincenty(coords_1, (i, j)).km < 15 for i, j in zip(df['Latitude'], df['Longitude'])]
print (mask)
[True, False, False, False]
```

Then filter by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing)

```
df1 = df[mask]
print (df1)
  Some_datas  Longitude  Latitude Some_other_datas
0          x    116.529    39.521                x
```

...and write to file:

```
df1.to_csv(file, index=False)
```